# Dividing an array into optimum no of equal sum sublists

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Hi I am trying to find what kind of data structure algorithm i have to use in this problem. I have two arrays one contains products weights and another contains costs. I have to divide products weights into optimum no of packages with equal weight over each package and cost of individual product or cost of total items should not be greater than $300 over each package after dividing.

Ex: weights = [1000,500,500] costs = [150,75,75]

We don't need to divide them into multiple packages because total cost of all the products was not more than $300. So we can send them as one package.

Ex: weights = [1000, 500, 500 ] costs = [200, 100, 100]

Now the cost of all the products was more than $300 so we have to divide them into packages with equal weights and each should not be more than $300 costly.

We can divide them into two packages one contains 1000 grams and another contains 1000 grams(500 + 500) and cost won't be more than $300.

I am not looking for code or something. I just need a hint or algorithm about how to proceed in dividing multiple packages thing.

Answer (score 0):

Finding a single subset with a given weight is NP hard. If you've some way to identify all the subsets of a given weight and whose costs are less than $300 then you need to solve an exact cover problem, which is NP hard in general. So you can't expect to find any algorithm with less than exponential complexity in the worst case.

But what I'd try here is this:

```
let W = total weight of all packages
let N = total number of packages
for k = 1, 2, 3, ..., N
    find all subsets of packages with weight W/k and cost less than $300
    if there's an exact cover: stop with solution.
```

You can find subsets of the right weight and cost using dynamic programming assuming the number of different weights and costs are small enough. You can find exact covers using the dancing links algorithm.